# What's the best approach for data validation between forms and models on Laravel 5?

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, models

I'm used to have model and form validation together, in another framework. But I'm migrating to Laravel and trying to understand its mindset.

What's the best approach for data validation? I've [seen](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/3) some [classes](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#form-model-binding) that help out on creating forms and validating requests, but isn't it unsafe to have models saving data without validating it before?

How could I integrate form (frontend), request (backend) and model validation so they all play nicely together? Or this is not done in the Laravel world at all?

Comment: There are meny ways, nothing is as best but a preference of your own so decide which one fits with your mindset.

Comment: [This is another approach](http://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-middleware-for-validation#.VjP2ctIrLIU) that, I use someetimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the best way I found to solve this matter was stitching together two Laravel extensions: [Ardent](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent), an Eloquent extension that includes validation, and a fork of [Laravalid](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/laravalid), that extends the Form with jQuery basic validation: that fork includes Ardent integration.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter in Laravel myself, I can tell a mind of a learner.

The first thing to understand is that Laravel is **very very very very very** abstract. It offers you thousands of solutions for a single problem. Since you're just starting out, I'm going to assume you're using Laravel 5 (5.1 to be more specific).

### The $this->validate() from Controllers

[You can use $this->validate() in your controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic).

```
class SomeController extends Controller {

      public function store(Request $request){
         $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
         ]);

         // This passed validation.
      }
}
```

### The Validation Facade

Inside the `config/app.php` you will find a `aliases` field that defines the Validator Facade as `'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class`. [You can make validators from basically anywhere](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#manually-creating-validators).

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|unique:emails|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // Error logic
    }

    // Store the blog post...
}
```

### Form Requests

Personally, I like Form Requests. They allow you to reuse validation logic defined once in any controller you feel like it. You can run in your project

```
php artisan make:request MyCustomRequest
```

That will generate a new request inside `app/Http/Requests` where you can write your rules inside the `rules method`. And then, when you want to use it, just type-hint your controller method.

Here is how to use it:

```
public function store(CompanyRequest $request){
    // This code will only be executed if the rules inside CompanyRequest
    // Are true.
}
```

Here is the file defining CompanyRequest.

```
class CompanyRequest extends Request {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'domain' => 'required|max:40'
        ];
    }

}
```

### Conclusion

There are probably a few more ways to do it. You can, for instance, use `Validator::make` facade from within your Eloquent models. Laravel offers multiple ways of handling basic problems. You just have to find what is best for you and major in it.

Comment: Yeah, you're showing the FormRequest objects that are shown in the video I linked in the question. My point is: how could we integrate that in the model and with the client side? Is there a way, or will I really need to copy validation rules at some places?

Comment: @igorsantos07 why do you want to integrate that in the model? You validate the data being given to the server and if it's all well, you create a new model and save it, if it's not a valid model, why create an invalid one? Just don't create it. As to the client side, it divides whether you're using Blade Views or building a REST API. But you have to keep in mind that those are 2 different problems. First you validate, then you return error messages. There are lots of ways to return messages as well, such as Flash Messages, resources/lang/xx/validation.php and the messages method in Resources.

Comment: I want to integrate because _people make mistakes_©. It's not hard to think once you can mistype a field or a value and your model will diligently save that invalid data (such as a storing an empty string in the database). Besides this, what you said is right: I'm focusing on Blade views here, but not talking about displaying feedback from server-side validation. I really meant client side validation, through traditional JS.

Comment: Well, I'd have to say that front-end validation has nothing to do with Laravel, really. You'd have to go for Javascript libraries and such. You don't want to validate server data, you just want to pre-validate the data before it gets to the server. That's Javascript responsibility.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But in the end that's all our job, and it poses duplicated code, defining validation rules repeatedly between client and server

Comment: Front-end validation are about enhancing user experience. Back-end validation are about protecting the intelligence of the software.

Comment: You can extend the Validator object so that it can return the rules as JSON then add the rules as an HTML tag like data-rules. Then use JavaScript to validate on the front-end.

Comment: Look into what I mentioned. You can return the rules to the view then have JS do front-end validation without having two sets of rules. It takes a bit of work but once you have it down, it's simple and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best method or not.
But I'm using this concept and its most popular way of validating forms in most popular CMS.

As usual the form action should point to a controller method. Inside controller method you can init a validator class like below.

```
$validation = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), with(new UserValidation)->getRules());

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('your route path ')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        }
```

Then in your controller use the namespace like .

```
use VendorName\PackageName\validations\UserValidation;
```

Here I put the validations in a separate folder called validations. Also notice that I'm using Package development concept in Laravel 5.x you can read more about that [here](http://www.walkswithme.net/laravel-5-package-development).

Then in that UserValidation class you can put all the validation rules.

```
class UserValidation {

    public function getRules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:200|unique:client',
            'address'=>'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ];
    }

}
```

This has several advantage the controller looks much neat and validation customization will be entirely separate file.
Also you can split up the route to a separate folder too.

Hope it make sense..

Comment: It seems a nice idea, in fact. I would maybe make things simpler by returning an array from the included file instead of having to call an instance method on a plain class. However, this does not answer what I asked, about integration on form, backend and frontend validations :(